# Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error

Tags: samba, restart

After updating Samba I am getting this error when logged in as a user. Does not occur as root. The details window runs unity-support-test but never stops. What is the error?

Comment: I'm getting this all the time with websites using Flash, so I'm interested in how to track down the actual source without guessing, too. +1

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? is there anything significant in the system logs? (Use the dash, type "log" and it should find the "log file viewer") What about any hidden error files in your user profile? (Ctrl+H to view hidden files in Nautlius)

Comment: If you can you may want to allow the system to create a bug in Launchpad for you. If it won't because of the problem with unity-support-test you may wish to file a bug against the apport package with `ubuntu-bug`.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!